# Get Session expiration time in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, session-timeout, session-cookies

Is there a way in Zend Framework or PHP to get the time until the Session(PHPSESSID cookie) expires?

Comment: which type of authentication are you using in Zend Framework?

Comment: session cookies never expire thats why they are called session cookies (without any time stamp) !!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know of any method provided by the framework to achieve this. But as soon as you know where ZF stores expiration time for its namespaces, you might be able to do something like this:

```
$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace( 'Zend_Auth' );
$session->setExpirationSeconds( 60 );

$timeLeftTillSessionExpires = $_SESSION['__ZF']['Zend_Auth']['ENT'] - time();
```

Comment: Well i guess it should be `$_SESSION['__ZF']['Zend_Auth']['ENVT'] - time();`

But still, thanks for your help!! Wouldn't have made it without your ;)